# how I can get any point on Q

Tags: geometry, computational-geometry

I have points A, B and C as in this picture:

[link](http://iscr.ru/photo/1416666924_IMG_20141122_161556.JPG)

I have the coordinates of A, B, and C. In this example, A = (1, 1), B = (4.5, 2), and C = (6, 5.5). Points Q1 and Q2 are on the line shown, where the distances from Q1 and Q2 to B are both equal to a number r (in this example, r = 3).

How I can get the coordinates of Q1 and Q2?

Thanks.

Comment: thanks boys for the minus vote

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic on this programming site because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume you have some geometry primitives, such as vector subtraction and vector lengths. Then, you can compute Q2 as follows (in pseudo-code):

```
r = 3
v = C.minus(B)
w = B.minus(A)
u = v.scaleBy(length(w)) + w.scaleBy(length(v))
Q2 = B.plus(u.scaleBy(r / length(u))
```

Here, `v.scaleBy(5)` returns a vector that has the x and y coordinates of `v` multiplied by 5. The functions `length`, `plus`, and `minus` should be self-explanatory.